# How to give font bold to first row data?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox with autocomplete feature which populates data in table format. I want the first row data to be bold.

My code:

```
   .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><table><tr><td width='200px'>" + item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></a>").appendTo(ul);
     };
```

Comment: why are you not using css?????

Comment: `.append("<a><table><tr style="font-weight: bold;">` ???

Comment: I only want the first row.It will make bold all the row data.@C-link

Answer (score 3):

**JS:**

```
$('table tr:first').css('font-weight','bold');
```

The jQuery selector finds the first tr :- **tr:first** of the table.

Just add this line after your code.

OR

add these lines to your css/style tag.

```
table tr:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to place this code?for jquery style?@shaunakde

Comment: Just add this line after your function which appends the html.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

CSS:

```
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

JS:

```
$('table tr:first').addClass('bold')
```

---

Or you can do that by using pure css,

```
table tr:first-child{ font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please modify my code.Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @Sumanta Are you expecting something like this.? `.append("<a><table><tr class='bold'>`

Comment: I am new to Jquery.kindly tell me where to place this code?" $('table tr:first').addClass('bold')".@Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Comment: @Sumanta oh.. fine.. After you appending the table, just execute that code.. For your reference http://jsfiddle.net/VS47v/

Comment: Really Thanks for the help.But the only problem is I am not getting where to place the code "" $('table tr:first').addClass('bold')"" my function is:jsfiddle.net/VS47v.Updated my code there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for that:

```
 table tr:nth-child(1){ font-weight:bold; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, call this after returning from autocomplete function call :

```
$('table tr:first').css('font-weight','bold');
```

Or you can put style directly in table like this :

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><table><tr style='font-weight:bold'><td width='200px'>" +
                         item.label + "</td>" + "<td width='110px'>" 
                         + item.val.split('~')[6] + "</td>" + "<td>" 
                         + item.val.split('~')[4] + "</td></tr></table></a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
     };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But where can i place this code.@bhushan kawadkar

Comment: You can put this after returning from auto complete or put style in table directly. See my answer.

Comment: This will make every row data as bold.@Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: But you are creating a new table everytime and apending it to ul, so in this case multiple tables are getting created. Can you show me JSFiddle to know what exactly you are doing and what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using css alone

```
table tr:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css as others said. But how about simply replacing your td tag with th which simply creates the bold text?

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8dz/)

And this is the basic standard for creating the table with heading.